# How do I block individual content items from search engines?

Tags: meta-tags

I need to create multiple landing pages for my food business running a Drupal 7 site, same page, different prices, offers, coupons, different OGP tags for Facebook posts etc.

So I will have dozens of multiple identical content pages, and I don't want to be penalized by Google. I could do this via Robots.txt or .htaccess, but is there a way to do this at the content page item level?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Metatag](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag) module for this purpose. Go to configuration page of metatag module and you can prevent google to index your node type.

Hope it will help.